# android touchevent for listActivity

Tags: android

I have created `ListActivity` of images I want touchevent just like `onItemClickListner`, how can I do it? I'm not finding any `onItemTochListener`.

Answer (score 1):

It's on the list view

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener( ... )
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set a new OnClickListener. The ListActivity class has a method called onListItemClicked which registers click and touch events for the items in the list view. Simply override this method with the code you want executed when a list item is pressed.